# Dynamically sized Uint8Array when receiving data over TCP network

Tags: javascript, tcp, deno

I have successfully built a simple TCP server, here is my code:

```js
const server = Deno.listen({ port:3000 })

for await (const conn of server) {
  let d = new Uint8Array(1024)

  await conn.read(d)

  console.log(d)
}
```

This works well, at some point, it’s not a big problem. However I don’t want to manually set the Uint8Array size and slices the uint8array by length received from `conn.read()`.

Is there any workaround to handle this?

Dynamically sized Uint8Array that received from `conn.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

Iterate the [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream):

```ts
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 3000 });

for await (const conn of server) {
  (async () => {
    const byteArr: number[] = [];
    for await (const chunk of conn.readable) byteArr.push(...chunk);
    const u8Arr = new Uint8Array(byteArr);
  })();
}
```

Use [`readAll`](https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/streams/conversion.ts?code#L362) from `deno.land/std`:

```ts
import { readAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/streams/conversion.ts";

const server = Deno.listen({ port: 3000 });

for await (const conn of server) {
  (async () => {
    const u8Arr = await readAll(conn);
  })();
}
```

You can read the source for [`Buffer#readFrom`](https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/io/buffer.ts?code#L195) to learn how [`readAll`](https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/streams/conversion.ts?code#L362) does it internally.

Be sure to read the manual page [HTTP Server APIs (low level) | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.24.0/runtime/http_server_apis_low_level), as it covers a lot of what you seem to be exploring/asking about.